# How much different is the business logic in enterprise applications vs mobile applications?

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, mobile, enterprise-architecture

only one thing after discuss my doubt i am a mobile developer and i am trying to adapt DDD, and i say adapt because a lot of information is related to backend applications

My doubt start because i have a User class that is part of my model (im using MVP), and also in terms of DDD it´s a domain object, i know business logic should be in Domain Layer, and here start my first question

1. My User class is not a plain object its also have functionality,
   methods like, storeUserInLocalDataBase or StoreCredentialsInKeyChain
   or createObjectWithJSON, this methods are related to the user so i
   left in User class, but keep a session is not part of business
   logic? the ability to remember the user credentials
   (StoreCredentialsInKeyChain) is not part of the business logic?, so
   in that way i think i should move that methods to the UserDomain
   class right?, and here start another doubt
2. If i have a UserDomain class that means when i made my domain model
   or UML my User class should interact with other classes and
   components and the main character in this business process should be
   the User right? thats the reason i named the class UserDomain
3. But what happened if there is a Mission model class as part of the
   UserDomain and a user can getCurrentMission?, this getCurrentMission
   is part of UserDomain or should be MissionDomain?
4. What happened if Mission class has more logic? should be in the
   Model class  like my first approach in the user class? or should i
   move that logic to the UserDomain class?, and if this happens with
   any other objects in UserDomain, my UserDomain class will be filled
   with a lot of logic from my Models classes and i guess this could be
   a problem or maybe not

So thats a few questions that i have i hope to be clear and you can understand why im so confused about this

Thanks, i will really appreciate your comments

Comment: Are you saying you have both a `User` class and a `UserDomain` class? What is the difference in purpose?

Comment: @JacquesB User class is like an entity with some helper methods, UserDomain is business related to the user

Comment: Not all proper OO application architecture is DDD, and not all DDD is proper architecture

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer so in what cases do you think DDD is a proper architecture?

Comment: Cases that are so complex, the application could easily be broken into many different applications... then there should be a compelling case  why the applications cannot be separated.

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer so you mean each application as a domain? and simple applications with only one domain don't have sense at all?

Comment: Yes, exactly. However, that does not mean you cannot apply some of the principals of DDD. The language negation planning part is great for every project. Also, be sure to keep the lines between the UI, business, and data clear. Not DDD doesn't mean no architecture.

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer thanks!, that helps to clarify my problem, by the way yesterday i was talking to a partner about business logic in mobile applications and he said most of the business logic is in the backend, mobile app maybe could have some business logic but different than backend business logic, what do you think about this?

Comment: I will post a response as an answer after this release I'm working on is finished

Answer (score 0):

If your phone gui maps to your web gui 1 to 1, you have a fairly easy issue to solve. Simply apply the MVC/MVP pattern properly. Your phone and web application can share everything except the View.

```
DB -> Business-Model -> Controller/Presenter -> View-Model -> Html Render/Desktop Gui
                                                     |------> Mobile App
```

Where you may have gone wrong, is that your models are ambiguous, that is to say, represent both both business entities and view models.

If there is substantial differences in the *presentation* but not business logic between the mobile and web apps, than you have to move the split lower down the chain:

```
DB -> Business-Model -> Business-Service -> Presenter -> View-Model -> GUI 
                                |->Mobile-Presenter -> M-View-Model -> GUI
```

And, if they work completely differently, then you have a lot of work...

```
DB -> Data-Service -> "  
             |------> "
```

In case it is not clear, you get your view-model to the mobile app via http/json

Comment: To add to this if you utilize a responsive UI approach it's really just the display that shifts depending the detected platform.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design